# How to add unique keys in a new column for repeated values in a different column within SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a table with a column with repeating values, and I want to add another column that has unique values for each distinct value in the first column.Here is a sample:

```
temp  Postal
1     42420
2     90032
3     60610
4     42420
5     98661
6     10024
7     10024
8     10024
```

Considering the above example, row 1 and 4 should have the same value , while 6,7 and 8 should share a value as well.

I wrote a query that implements my intended feature but on a limited scale:

```
UPDATE `train` 
SET `new_column`=(SELECT MIN(temp) FROM train WHERE `Postal`= '42420')
 WHERE `Postal`='42420';
```

This works well but is unscalable for large datasets(the one I am using has 9801 rows). Is there away to make it work automatically for the whole table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `group by` to get the smallest temp by Postal, then using `inner join` to get the smallest temp per record :

```
update train t
inner join (
  select Postal, min(temp) as min_temp
  from train
  group by Postal
) as s on s.Postal = t.Postal
set t.new_column = s.min_temp
```

Result :

```
temp    Postal  new_column
1       42420   1
2       90032   2
3       60610   3
4       42420   1
5       98661   5
6       10024   6
7       10024   6
8       10024   6
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/L_zV-tdN)

Answer (score 1):

If you're running MySQL 8+, or a recent version of MariaDB, then I suggest *not* doing this update.  The reason is that any time your data changes, e.g. by adding a new record with the same `Postal` value, you might be forced to run the update again.  Instead, just use the following select query:

```sql
SELECT temp, Postal, MIN(temp) OVER (PARTITION BY Postal) AS new_column
FROM train
ORDER BY temp;
```

You could place this query into a view for easy access.  This query should benefit from the following index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON train (Postal, temp);
```